# Log transfer using syslog-ng 3.3.5

Tags: syslog-ng

I want to transfer client logs to a log server but the problem i  am facing is that each time client's file gets modified , whole file is transfered to log server so i am getting redundant message at log server. How can i overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you probably have syslog-ng configured to send the old messages as well. 
There should be an option to disable that, IIRC, read-old-records(no).

Regards,

Robert